# Box2D Contact Listener?

Tags: ios, collision-detection, box2d

I am trying to use the Box2D contact listener in my game. I know Ray Wenderlich has a tutorial on how to do this but I find it confusing and I wanted to see if someone could help explain to me how to do this.

Do I need to have a specific class just for this contact listener or can it just be a few basic lines of code in my CCScene class?

Can someone offer some insight on this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: take a look at box2d documentation. everything is explained there very good. There are even full examples of how to use contact listener. People will not waste their time if you even don't want to read the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement a new class for the collision or say contact listener based on some criteria as tag no. i have an example for you.

// ContactListener.h

```
#import "Box2D.h"

class ContactListener : public b2ContactListener 
{
private: 
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
};
```

// ContactListener.mm

```
#import "ContactListener.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "BodyNode.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        BodyNode* bNodeA = (BodyNode*)bodyA->GetUserData();
        BodyNode* bNodeB = (BodyNode*)bodyB->GetUserData();

        if ((bNodeA.tag == GameSceneNodeTagBall && bNodeB.tag == GameSceneNodeTagHole) || 
            (bNodeA.tag == GameSceneNodeTagHole && bNodeB.tag == GameSceneNodeTagBall)) 
        {
            switch (bNodeA.tag) {
                case GameSceneNodeTagBall:
                    if ([bNodeA isKindOfClass:[Ball class]]) {
                        Ball* ball = (Ball*)bNodeA;
                        ball.sprite.visible = NO;
                        [[GameScene sharedGameScene] gameOver];
                    }
                    break;
                case GameSceneNodeTagHole:
                    if ([bNodeB isKindOfClass:[Ball class]]) {
                        Ball* ball = (Ball*)bNodeB;
                        ball.sprite.visible = NO;
                        [[GameScene sharedGameScene] gameOver];
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of ball and hole collision. You can use this as per your requirement.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks!

to check the collision only for one time :

```
// ContactListener.mm

    #import "ContactListener.h"
    #import "cocos2d.h"
    #import "BodyNode.h"
    #import "GameScene.h"

    void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
    {
        b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
        b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL)
        {
            BodyNode* bNodeA = (BodyNode*)bodyA->GetUserData();
            BodyNode* bNodeB = (BodyNode*)bodyB->GetUserData();

            if ((bNodeA.tag == GameSceneNodeTagBall && bNodeB.tag == GameSceneNodeTagHole) || 
                (bNodeA.tag == GameSceneNodeTagHole && bNodeB.tag == GameSceneNodeTagBall)) 
            {
                switch (bNodeA.tag) {
                    case GameSceneNodeTagBall:
                        if ([bNodeA isKindOfClass:[Ball class]] && isBallCollision == NO) {
                            Ball* ball = (Ball*)bNodeA;
                            ball.sprite.visible = NO;
                            isBallCollision = YES;
                            [[GameScene sharedGameScene] gameOver];
                        }
                        break;
                    case GameSceneNodeTagHole:
                        if ([bNodeB isKindOfClass:[Ball class]] && isBallCollision == NO) {
                            Ball* ball = (Ball*)bNodeB;
                            ball.sprite.visible = NO;
                            isBallCollision = YES;
                            [[GameScene sharedGameScene] gameOver];
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                           isBallCollision = NO;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I actually have solved this since then but the current issue I am facing is doing a one sided platform. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: sorry i don't get your use of "a one sided platform" please explain a bit more

Comment: Ok so when I do collision detection pretty much like you do here, the collision will perform simply if my main sprite hits the 'side' of this platform. What I want to achieve is, pretty much the same effect as they do in Doodle Jump, if you hit the side of the platform, the character won't 'land' on it unless it hits the top.

Comment: Ok i got what you want to do.i don't know what exactly we have to but i think we can achieve this by checking the collision of legs of the character and the platform when the X position of character is greater than the X position of platform.

Comment: Ok so you mean getting the main character's bottom x by getting th current X and subtracting it by half the sprite height and then doing the same for the platform except adding half the sprite height to get the top X. Is that what I should do?

Comment: Yes, i think so, will be a solution for this and put them in a condition that the collision check will only effective when the character X position is greater than platform top X.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! I'll mark your answer as a accepted answer. But I have one last issue, is there any way to prevent multiple callbacks of a collision detection. For example I have a code that increased a label by one point for each collision but the issue is that it updates multiple times so the label score ends up being like 60 for each collision. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes you can put a flag value for checking the multiple collision if collision already happened you can by pass the code of score incrementand reset the value when collision is over. Like you can put a bool value.

Comment: Ah I see! Would you mind updating your code example to reflect this? Then I will accept your answer right away :)

Comment: Ill offer you a bounty if necessary! :)

Comment: I am busy in some other work i will post one more answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, one very last minor question. Will this still recognize multiple collisions though? I just want my code to fire once PER collision. Is that what this code will do?

Comment: sure No problem with multiple collision as soon as the character pass away  from the stage the bool will be reset as we do that in our default case :)

Comment: if there is any problem with this code we can do the resetting part in some other way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6818/discussion-between-haroon-and-ibrad-apps)